# Customising NetBeans Platform Harness

Tags: netbeans-8, netbeans-platform

my question is about developing a suite of applications using NetBeans Platform 8.x and modifying the harness.

We would like to modify the harness independently for the apps, and be able to commit that into source control. The modified harnesses work when they replace the existing one in the NetBeans installation. We have modified the harnesses and placed them inside the suite directory (as just a directory) for the command line app and the GUI app. Ideally we would like to carry on using the platform installed at the default location but modify the harness per app?

What we have tried:
We defined:
`suite.dir=${basedir}`

`harness.dir=${suite.dir}/harness`

This works great for the clean and build targets. But it does not work for the GUI invoked package as installers action.

Looking at the source for:
org.netbeans.modules.apisupport.installer.actions.BuildInstallersAction() 
it is not immediately clear how to achieve this because it makes use of `InstalledFileLocator.getDefault().locate`
to find the harness.

Is there away to direct the installer 'build' to use the modified harness in `${suite.dir}/harness` ?

Or is the only option to register our own action to replace `BuildInstallersAction()` ? - if that is possible?

We are trying to avoid having to copy the entire platform source (as seems to be suggested in harness\README - may be I have misunderstood it?) as well, we only modify the harness.

Thanks

Trevor